# Eclipse Method could not be resolved in a simple program C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, methods

I have an issue with Eclipse Indigo complaining that methods of a class couldn't be resolved, but compiling anyway and working correctly (AFAIK).  It's a very simple program.  Here is Population.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "Population.h"

Population::Population() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Population::~Population() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void Population::initializePop(int numBits, int N) {

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        x[i] = (char*) calloc(numBits, sizeof(char));
        for(int j=0; j<numBits; j++) {
            if( rand() < 0.5 )
                x[i][j] = 0;
            else
                x[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

}

char** Population::getX() {
    return x;
}

void Population::printStuff() {
    std::cout << "Whatever";
}
```

Now, I build that code and everything is fine.  In another project within Eclipse, I'm calling this code like this:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "cute.h"
#include "ide_listener.h"
#include "cute_runner.h"
#include "Population.cpp"

void testPopulationGeneration() {
    Population* p = new Population;
    int N = 10;
    int bits = 4;
    char** pop;

    ASSERTM("Population variable improperly initialized", dynamic_cast<Population*>(p));

    std::cout << p->printStuff();
    std::cout << "Ok...";
    p->initializePop(bits, N);

    pop = p->getX();
    ASSERTM("Pop not correct size.", sizeof(pop) == 10);
}
```

As you can see I'm also running the CUTE plugin for TDD in C++.  It doesn't complain when I declare p as type Population and the first assertion passes.  I'm somewhat new to C++, but I did make sure to add the project that Population.cpp is from to the include path for the test project.

It's not a huge deal as it's not affecting anything obvious to me, but it's still very annoying.  I don't see a situation where it should do this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

In your project explorer window, right click on your project -> Index -> Rebuild

Answer (score 10):

This could be an indexing issue related to external `#include` headers not found. Follow the steps below and see if it helps:

1. Go to each of your custom `#include` (e.g. `"cute.h"`) and press
   `F3` (i.e. "Show declaration"); see if it's able to access that file
   or not; if not copy those files on some notepad
2. If the file is not accessible, then locate it paths in your
   directory structure; e.g. "cute.h" and "a.h" are located at,
   "`C://Eclipse/MyWork/Workspace/Project/include_1`" and
   "ide_listener.h" is located
   at,"`C://Eclipse/MyWork/Workspace/Project/include_2`", then copy both
   the folder paths on some notepad
3. Inside Eclipse go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General ->
   Paths and Sybmols`; you will see several tabs as `Includes`,
   `Sybmols`, `Library Paths` ...
4. Click `Library Paths -> Add -> Workspace... -> <locate the above
   folder paths>` and press OK
5. Let the indexer rebuild; now again follow the step (1); hopefully
   the files should be accessible
6. For future safety for larger files, go to `Window -> Preferences ->
   C/C++ -> Editor -> Scalability -> "Enable scalability mode when
   ..."` and set the number of lines to some big number such as
   `500000` and press "OK";

The last step is needed, because when your file grows in line number and if exceeds the above number then eclipse will stop showing definitions for some "*scalability*" reasons, even though it would have indexed.

Comment: I tried going through all my includes and Eclipse can find all of the sources, so that appears not to be my problem.

Comment: I am not seeing the "Library Paths" under Paths and Symbols on my ADT. Anyone knows where this is moved to now? Thanks.

Comment: @inder, did you mean `Windows > Preferences > Debug/Release > Source Lookup Path`?

Comment: This solution works for me, thanks. I am using Eclipse mars. 2 on mac.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(pointer)` returns the size of the pointer (4 on 32-bit systems and 8 on 64-bit), not the size of what it points to! Save the dimensions in the class, and add a function to return them.

Also, in `initializePop` shouldn't you allocate the actual `X` array?

```
X = calloc(N, sizeof(char *));
```

Or rather, you should use `new` for allocation since you are using C++:

```
X = new char* [N];
```

and later:

```
X[i] = new char [numbits];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It doesn't answer the question but the sizeof tip helped me out.  I guess I've been using higher level languages for too long.  Little rusty on the basics like that.  It almost seems like a hack to just store the sizes along with the array itself, but I guess if the size of the array is going to be command-line input, there's no better way to do it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Not that i'm any expert at all but i just had a similar problem using.empty for whatever reason it will work if you change char to string minor change but resolved the issue on my program