# Error While Working With I/O

Tags: c++, io

So I have this very basic code that should work, however, I keep getting two errors:

```
1. Method 'open' could not be resolved.
2. Method 'close' could not be resolved.
```

I'm new to C++, but I've seen this used tons of other places, but yet its not working for me. Would someone please explain to me what exactly is going on? Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

I have a similar, longer program I'm working with and the something is occurring. Thanks!

Comment: [Runs fine here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4bf057d91786fb2)

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you using any particular IDE?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm using Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Ok, so if its working fine for you then it must be something wrong with the IDE.

Comment: It's odd but I got it to work by closing Eclipse and reopening.

Comment: See this if help http://stackoverflow.com/a/19166935/4499919