# Function strdup() cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse

Just installed new eclipse neon for c++ coding.

`strdup()` fails to be resolved, although I can see the function signature and describe when I'm looking for it using Ctrl+Space, same for `strtok()`

```
Deck::Deck(string the_deck, int n) {
  const char * tmp_deck = the_deck.c_str();
  char * c_deck = strdup(tmp_deck);
  char *token;
  token = strtok(c_deck, " ");
  while (token != NULL) {
    if (isdigit(token[0]))
        cards.push_back(new NumericCard(token));
    else
        cards.push_back(new FigureCard(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}}

Error: Function 'strdup' could not be resolved
```

Tried this : [Eclipse Method could not be resolved in a simple program C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124882/eclipse-method-could-not-be-resolved-in-a-simple-program-c) but it didn't help.

I'm using Win 10 OS with MinGW, also, everything is working fine on Visual Studio.

[image: Attached Photo]

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system, compiler, library?  Eclipse's idea of what is available may be incorrect.

Comment: Also, please post the _exact, unedited_ text of the error message you got.

Comment: "What OS" as asked above is indeed pretty vital as at least is not a standard function `strdup` .

Comment: updated required details. thanks

Comment: you need `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the resolving of strtok(), still same problem with strdup()

Comment: Still, note that `strdup` is not standard C++, using it introduces a dependency on POSIX.